# Как связать ObservableCollection с DataView

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, observablecollection, typed-dataset

Подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно ли связать `ObservableCollection` с `DataView`?

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> DataBase
{
    get { return р_DataBase; }
    set
    {
        р_DataBase = value;
        base.RaisePropertyChangedEvent("DataBase");
    }
}
```

и

```
public DataView Users
{
    get
    {
        return this.dataBase.dataset.DataTablePersons.DefaultView;
    }        
}
```

Comment: И `ObservableCollection`, и `DataSet/DataTable` являются хранилищем (источником) _данных_. Привязка _данных_ осуществляется к UI-компоненту. То есть любой из этих источников вы можете привязать к какому-нибудь графическому компоненту, например, датагриду. Но в чём смысл их привязки друг к другу? Что они должны делать?

Comment: Привязка работает со свойствами зависимости (DependencyProperty), которые могут быть только у объектов, участвующих в системе свойств зависимости (DependencyObject). Указанные классы не являются DependencyObject, поэтому привязка с ними работать не будет!